# How to redefine a command to contain itself in it by maintaining it's syntax unchanged

Tags: math-mode, macros, environments, definition

I need to use the `\ae` command inside an equation as a variable, in order to put it in a math environment though I'm forced to use `\textit{\ae}`.

Is there a way to just write `\ae` in the math environment and get the result as there would have been `\textit{\ae}` written?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the definition of `\ae` and reuse the name. One has to do it with `\LetLtxMacro` in order to avoid infinite loops.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,letltxmacro}

\makeatletter
% \serra@ae is the same as \ae
\LetLtxMacro\serra@ae\ae
\let\ae\relax % remove the definition for \ae
\DeclareRobustCommand{\ae}{%
  \TextOrMath{\serra@ae}{\text{\normalfont\itshape\serra@ae}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Here is \ae{} in text mode.

Here is $\ae$ in math mode. Also in subscripts: $X_{\ae}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, I'd prefer to do

```
\newcommand{\mae}{\text{\normalfont\itshape\ae}}
```

and use `\mae` in math mode.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend the following, as I think it would be better practise to either just use `\textit{\ae}` or define another macro like

```
\newcommand*\mae{\textit{ae}}
```

but the following does this redefinition using `\edef` which defines the macro to be the expanded stuff which follows. Expansion of everything in that `\edef` is prohibited by using `\noexpand`, except for `\ae` which is expanded once using `\unexpanded\expandafter{\ae}`.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\edef\ae
  {%
    \relax\noexpand\ifmmode
      \noexpand\textit{\unexpanded\expandafter{\ae}}%
    \noexpand\else
      \unexpanded\expandafter{\ae}%
    \noexpand\fi
  }


\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \ae = \textit{\ae}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the newcommand does work, but the edef unfortunately doesn't

Comment: @EdoardoSerra it does in my minimal document above.

Comment: It worked by putting it as the last element in the preamble, anywhere else doesn't work, don't know why though.

Comment: @EdoardoSerra in that case put an `\AtBeginDocument{...}` around it.