# special characters in equation

Tags: equations, symbols, turkish

I need to use a special character `{\i}` in a equation, but it is escaped inside the \begin{equation} block although it appear clearly in text. I have tried `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` and
`\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` packages but it doesn't work for equation block, could you help me please? Thank you in advance

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301).   For me, `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\i $\i$
\end{document}` shows that there is no difference with `\i` in math mode or text mode.  Please use something like this to create a  [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) that  that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.  This will also help to clarify exactly what the issue is.

Comment: @PeterGrill When I compile your MWE with pdflatex, I do get a warning `LaTeX Warning: Command \i invalid in math mode on input line 3.`. However, the output is equal inside and outside math environments, as you say.

Comment: Does in  `\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document} 
\i $\text{\i}\imath$ 
\end{document}` either `\text{\i}` or `\imath` give you the desired output?

Comment: @marmot: What?? Are we supposed to actually look at the warnings? :-).  I didn't notice it as the question seemed to imply that the problem was in how they were displayed.

Comment: Thank you very much firstly, you were right, error was bacause of my class file (.cls) the {\i} character displays similar to beta letter in equation. But i solve the problem with \textnormal{\i} or \textrm{\i} command in equation. Thanks again

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is solved by comments

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if I understood the question properly, however, this is what I understood

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,letltxmacro}

\makeatletter
% \user@i is the same as \i
\LetLtxMacro\user@i\i
\let\i\relax % remove the definition for \i
\DeclareRobustCommand{\i}{%
  \TextOrMath{\user@i}{\text{\normalfont\user@i}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\i

i

\begin{equation}
    \i\ i
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The code has been taken and slightly modified from the first answer to this question: [How to redefine a command to contain itself in it by maintaining it's syntax unchanged](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/437781/how-to-redefine-a-command-to-contain-itself-in-it-by-maintaining-its-syntax-unc)

Comment: Thank you very much firstly, yes you understood me perfectly :)  in your file it seems working well but maybe bacause of my class file (.cls) the {\i} character displays similar to beta letter. But i solve the problem with \textnormal{\i} or \textrm{\i} command in equation. Thanks again